# dismax query syntax

Tags: solr, dismax

The query for standard request handler is as follows
field1:(keyword1 OR keyword2) OR field2:(keyword1 OR keyword2) OR field3:(keyword1 OR keyword2) AND field4:(keyword3 OR keyword4) AND field5:(keyword5)

How the same above query can be written for dismax request handler

Answer (score 0):

There are three kinds of phrses in dismax
-mandatory  (the word is preceded by (+) mark : means that keywords must be exists both in one document (in one search result)
-prohibited (the word is preceded by (-) mark : means that keywords must not be in the search result
-and optional which is the default and not preceded by any mark : means that one of the keywords at least in the search result

to filter query against fields you can use the (qf) parameter 
qf=name title auther ISBN 
or 
qf = name to search only on name field